# NPoco using LINQ where clauses in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, petapoco, npoco

I am very interested in the use of LINQ in NPoco (microORM based on PetaPoco), which theoretically [can be used to specify simple where clauses](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2013/04/20/npoco-2-0/). I have been testing them in vb.net but I am not able to achieve the desired results.

**Error details:**

> variable 'x' of type 'MyProjectName.App' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined.

**Code:**

```
Imports NPoco
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class NPocoTest

    Public Sub doTest()
        Using db As IDatabase = New Database(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("mydbconnectionstring"), NPoco.DatabaseType.MySQL)
            Dim app As App = db.FetchBy(Of App)(Function(sql) sql.Where(Function(x) x.name = "groupee")).FirstOrDefault
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class App
    Public Property SID As Integer
    Public Property name As String
End Class
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try the latest version using the `Query<T>()` method. This has not and will not be tested with VB.net but if you are most welcome to make a PR if you fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Schotime, I will take a look at it ASAP. And thank you for your work with NPoco, it very useful for my interests. By the way: in order to avoid using the var name as text I used this:`Public Shared Function GetPropertyName(Of t)(ByVal PropertyExp As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of t))) As String \ Return TryCast(PropertyExp.Body, System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression).Member.Name \ End Function`.